# SQL Server Authentication to Windows Authentication for single user

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication

Is it somehow possible to change the security setting for a single (already existing) user from SQL Server Authentication to Windows Authentication?

The security setting on server-level is set to mixed mode (so both SQL Server Authentication and Windows authentication). For a new login I can choose which authentication mode to set.

But for an existing user (a login that is, created with SQL Server Authentication) the radio-buttons are greyed out. I would like to change this for a number of users without having to recreate these users, but I can't seem to find how this can be done.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking for users or logins?

Comment: for logins (in SSMS under tab security - Logins)

Comment: No, you can't change a SQL Login to a Windows Login.

Comment: Does the database server use a domain server?

Comment: The database does use a domain server and i have admin rights on both.

Comment: Just change the *client's* connection string to use Windows Authentication. And then simply delete those SQL Auth users. As far as creating these users: don't. Just assign them to an AD group such as `Allowed SQL users`, then give the *group* the necessary permissions in SQL Server. So all you need to do to enable/disable a user is add/remove them from the AD group.